# Visual overlays after GraphViz "dot" does its work?

Tags: graphviz

I'm using GraphViz's `dot` program to layout a digraph for me, and the results are satisfactory.  I'm using `splines=ortho` to get nodes and edges placed attractively and without excessive overlap.

Sometimes I want to take a graph that's already been laid out in this manner, and add some additional visual commentary to it, *without modifying the underlying layout*.

For example, I want to add a sequence of arrows that show a traversal order of various nodes in the graph.  But I want each arrow to be a straight line segment that totally ignores the routing that was applied when originally laying out the graph.

The idea is I'd show my users two versions of the laid-out graph: the one GraphViz produced, and then another version where my commentary (arrows, etc.) are basically a visual overlay.

Is there a clean and/or easy way to do this?

My preference is to accomplish it entirely via a `.dot` file, rather than using the GraphViz API(s) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

- Use the **layer** attribute to define 2 layers - one with commentary and one without.  Layers are discussed here: https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf.  Note that only postscript output is useful, but it can be converted to other formats.
- Produce the uncommented output with **-Tdot** option.  Then add any desired commentary as dot commands to the file.  Run that edited file through **neato -n** (or **neato -n2**)